# Set properties of text box when combobox selection is made WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

how to Set properties of text box when combobox selection is made . foe example set background and IsEnabled property of text box when a combo box selection is made. I want it Purely in XAML not in code behind. i use MVVM

Comment: This question is similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561820/wpf-visibility-of-a-ui-element-based-on-combo-selection

Answer (score 0):

How to enable textBox1 only when SelectedItems is 1

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="246,177,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=comboBox1, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"></Setter>
                     </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox> 
    <ComboBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="246,119,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

I think only with XAML you cannot achieve the condition Value ="1" or "3", i.e. a relation in a data trigger more complex than a equality.

For this case you need a converter.
This link could help you

[How to get DataTemplate.DataTrigger to check for greater than or less than?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793926/how-to-get-datatemplate-datatrigger-to-check-for-greater-than-or-less-than)

Comment: How to have two or more condition in data triggers, or specifying more than one value for the property for example <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbInstrumentType, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="1" >
 <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"  />
                                    </DataTrigger>. i want to specify more than 1 value for SelectedIndex

Answer (score 0):

You can use a datatrigger for combo's selected object. Have a look to this previous question: [WPF Visibility of a UI element based on combo selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561820/wpf-visibility-of-a-ui-element-based-on-combo-selection)

Try to generate a trigger when selecteditem is `{x:Null}`. For that, you will need to put your controls inside a DataTemplate and the put the trigger in the template's triggers collection.

Here is a sample code (not tested, please check by your own):

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="246,177,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsEnabled" Value="True" /> 

<ComboBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="246,119,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

<DataTemplate.Triggers> 
     <Trigger SourceName="comboBox1" Property="ComboBox.SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}"> 
         <Setter TargetName="textbox2" Property="TextBox.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
     </Trigger> 
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: can we do this <MultiDataTrigger>
 <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
 <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbInstrumentType, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="1" />
 <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbInstrumentType, Path=SelectedIndex}"Value="2" />                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbInstrumentType, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="3" />
 </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"  /> </MultiDataTrigger>

Comment: looks like you are taking the inverse logic. Why not to check just for SelectedItem==null?

Comment: can we do it using SelectedItem != null

Comment: I don't think so. Trigger will check against positive equality. So, what you have to do, is to set the default style in your other controls for the case SelectedItem!=null. then create a simple trigger for SelectedItem Value="{x:Null}"

Comment: I want a text box to be enabled when a combo box selection is made else it will be disabled. First when the application runs also the text box should be disabled, and only if combobox selection is made textbox should get enabled. Purely in XAML as i am following MVVM i dont want it in code behind.

Comment: that's quiet easy and consistent with my recommendation: create a text control with isenabled="true", then create a combobox with selecteditem=null (explicitly) and datatrigger for element=thecombo, property=isselected, value=null with setter element=thetextbox, property=isenabled, value=false. When you start the application, the trigger should be launched and the textbox will be disabled until you select something in the combo. Notice that the trigger is in the combobox.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have to much time to try by myself a complete code, I have added a code portion to my answer, please check. It is important to put the controls in a datatemplate.

Comment: Can we have condition like Selected Index is greater than 0

Comment: no, not possible with pure xaml: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793926/how-to-get-datatemplate-datatrigger-to-check-for-greater-than-or-less-than